# .htaccess configuration to mask site?

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, redirect

I own a domain on godaddy (rainychat.com) and i have an app on Openshift (rainychat-jgal.rhcloud.com)

Currently i have a forwarding rule on godaddy so when a user goes to rainychat.com it is redirected to rainychat-jgal.rhcloud.com

So far so good. What i'm lacking now is that i want my .htaccess file on my app server to make it so when a it is requested rainychat-jgal.rhcloud.com, it is shown to the user instead rainychat.com in the browser.

This is what i tried, not working however...

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /  Not sure if this line is useful?

RewriteRule ^rainychat-jgal.rhcloud.com$ rainychat.com [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple just change

RewriteRule ^rainychat-jgal.rhcloud.com$ rainychat.com [L] and add a / like this

RewriteEngine On

## RewriteBase /  Not sure if this line is useful?

RewriteRule ^rainychat-jgal.rhcloud.com/ rainychat.com [L]

otherwise the server address wont be able to reroute itself to the isp of the domain which is creating your error you described.